# How to upgrade chrome version in Webdriver Container

Tags: java, docker, selenium, webdriver, containers

I use Docker with Webdriver Containers for UI tests wirtten in Java. Chrome in container has version 62 but current version is 80. I don't know how upgrade chrome in container. 
My dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the capabilities of the browser.

```
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
        capabilities.setCapability("browser", "chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("browser_version", "80");
```

Hope this is what you were expecting